# Passing an array of strings and sorting them (in C)

Tags: c, arrays, function, sorting, c-strings

So I'm having trouble with a programming assignment that is due tomorrow. The program is supposed to do quite a few things, but I'm running into a problem when I try to pass an array of strings into a function that sorts them in alphabetical order. My function to print the strings works fine before the Sort function is called, but when I try to print after I get random characters and sometimes only one or two strings print instead of all three. Here is the code from my Sort function:

```
void Sort (char **arr)
{

   char s1[256];
   char s2[256];
   char s3[256];

   strcpy(s1, arr[0]);
   strcpy(s2, arr[1]);
   strcpy(s3, arr[2]);


   if(s1[0] <= s2[0] && s2[0] <= s3[0])
   {
      arr[0] = s1;
      arr[1] = s2;
      arr[2] = s3;
   } 
   else if(s1[0] <= s3[0] && s3[0] <= s2[0])
   {
      arr[0] = s1;
      arr[1] = s3;
      arr[2] = s2;
   }
   else if(s2[0] <= s1[0] && s1[0] <= s3[0])
   {
      arr[0] = s2;
      arr[1] = s1;
      arr[2] = s3;
   }
   else if(s2[0] <= s3[0] && s3[0] <= s1[0])
   {
      arr[0] = s2;
      arr[1] = s3;
      arr[2] = s1;
   }
   else if(s3[0] <= s2[0] && s2[0] <= s1[0])
   {
      arr[0] = s3;
      arr[1] = s2;
      arr[2] = s1;
   }
   else
   {
      arr[0] = s3;
      arr[1] = s1;
      arr[2] = s2;
   }

}
```

I am sure that there are easier ways to do this than the long if statement but we're required to make the program using only what we've learned in class so far. I also apologize if I'm making some novice mistake as I'm rather new to the C language. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: your comparisons are only comparing one character (e.g. `s1[0]`) and not the entire string.  Also, as I hope you've realized, you need to completely rethink your sorting strategy.  Listing every permutation is not feasible.

Comment: It's hard to advise you, since we don't know what you've learned in class so far, but I notice that you're not copying the strings back into `arr`, you're *filling `arr` with pointers to arrays that are variables local to this function.* If you don't yet know why that's Ultra Bad, just take my word for it and `strcpy` the strings back into place.

Comment: I couldn't think of a way to do it comparing more than one character. And I realize in a practical situation it wouldn't be feasible, but in this situation there is no more than three strings. In a practical situation I would also have more resources at my disposal. Do you have any recommendations to help set me on the right path? I am also new to sorting algorithms.

Comment: Ahh thanks so much for pointing that out Beta. I've made the same mistake in similar situations before!

Comment: **Break the big task down into smaller tasks.** Write a function that takes two strings (`char *`) and returns a bool; `true` if the first string comes before the second, alphabetically, `false` otherwise. And how do you determine that? Look at the first characters, and return `true` if a<b, `false` if b>a. And if a=b? Then look at the second characters the same way, then the third characters, and if you make it to the end (and both strings end at the same time), then the strings are equal so return `false`.

Comment: After changing my function to copy the strings back into arr it works now! But I'm going to make changes like you suggested so I can learn some proper coding and not just exhaust a list of permutations. Sorry for making such an obvious mistake.. And I appreciate all of the quick help and replies!

Answer (score 0):

```
void Sort (char **arr)
```

understand what  `char **arr` really means.
it can also be written as `char arr[][]`
which may be a little more human readable to you.

the bracket contents can be left empty, or you can have a number in there indicating the size of each dimension.  Since you have `char s1[256]` then logically you should be doing or somehow enforcing `char arr[][256]` in your **Sort** function.

I believe your fundamental problem is doing `Sort (char **arr)`.
when you do `arr[1]` within the function, the compiler does not know how far to advance the pointer in memory.  When your function header is `Sort( char arr[][256])` then when you do `arr[1]` the compiler knows to move the pointer in memory 256 units, where the unit is the size of whatever type your **arr** variable is declared as.  And the sizeof( char ) is 1 byte.

Now you don't have to do it with brackets, you can still do it by `Sort( **arr )`  In that case for the first instance within your function you would do

```
arr+(256*0) = s1;   /* wrong, 256 should be a 1 */
arr+(256*1) = s2;   /* wrong, 256 should be a 1 */
arr+(256*2) = s3;   /* wrong, 256 should be a 1 */
```

correction to above,
based on how the variable arr is declared, the 256 should be a 1.  An oversight on my part.

Below is a sample code, that i did test, using gcc 4.3.4 compiler, and the resulting output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   char aa[10][256];
   char *p;

   p = *aa;

   printf("sizeof aa        = %d\n", sizeof( aa ) );
   printf("sizeof aa[0]     = %d\n", sizeof( aa[0] ) );
   printf("sizeof *aa       = %d\n", sizeof( *aa ) );
   printf("sizeof aa[0][0]  = %d\n", sizeof( aa[0][0] ) );
   printf("sizeof **aa      = %d\n", sizeof( **aa ) );

   printf("address aa       = %p\n", aa );
   printf("address aa[0]    = %p\n", aa[0] );

   printf("address aa[1]    = %p\n", aa[1] );
   printf("address aa+1     = %p\n", aa+1 );

   printf("\n");

   printf("address of p     = %p\n", p );
   printf("address of p+1   = %p\n", p+1 );
   printf("address of p+256 = %p\n", p+256 );
}
```

output:

```
sizeof aa        = 2560
sizeof aa[0]     = 256
sizeof *aa       = 256
sizeof aa[0][0]  = 1
sizeof **aa      = 1
address aa       = 0x7ffd38d602a0
address aa[0]    = 0x7ffd38d602a0
address aa[1]    = 0x7ffd38d603a0
address aa+1     = 0x7ffd38d603a0

address of p     = 0x7ffd38d602a0
address of p+1   = 0x7ffd38d602a1
address of p+256 = 0x7ffd38d603a0
```

Comment: You didn't test this, did you?

Comment: you can also think it as char* [ ] so the compiler knows that it is an array of pointers to char (what a string array really is). char** is fine